# No command running on Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-prompt, windows-7-x64

I recently installed Python 2.7.6 for 64 bit Windows7. I am trying to run few commands like cd, pwd etc and it is not running either on Windows Command Prompt, or Python Commnad Line. and i am getting the follwoing error:

```
>>cd Desktop

File "<stdin>", line 1

  cd Desktop
           ^
```

I am also not able to execute any .py codes

(I cannot post image as i dont have enough reputations)

Comment: you can take a print of your screen, upload it and post it as a link here rather

Comment: Did you put your Python folder into the PATH environment variable? (System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > PATH')  E.g. If I installed Python 2.7 into C:\Python27, then I would have "C:\Python27" in the PATH.  Append extra locations with ;

Comment: From your desktop - type windows-R - type "cmd" and hit Enter - should give you a command-line window. Type "python -V" and hit Enter - should tell you what version of Python you have. If not, you may need to add Python to your system path.

Comment: `cd` is an UNIX command and not python

Comment: `cd Desktop` would work without being into the python command prompt. type `exit()` to quit python and try `cd Desktop` again

Comment: Thanks a lot to all the guyz. After i exited from python prompt it started working

Answer (score 2):

The Python interpreter doesn't accept shell/batch commands, but only valid python code. What you are trying to do in your example would translate like this in python:

```
import os
os.chdir("Desktop")
```

What you did is start the Python interpreter in interactive mode (or maybe did you start IDLE). To run a python script saved in a file from the command line, try

```
C:\Python33\python.exe your_script.py
```

(change the path to python.exe according to your installation). If you installed Python fully, you should be able to launch scripts by double clicking on `.py` files.

If you use IDLE, see [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/idle.html?highlight=idle). You can open a script from the menu and run it.

*(Note that `pwd` is not a valid command for the Windows shell either (use `cd` without argument instead.)*